# How to get privateip address from Autoscaling group

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I'm writing a cloudformation template in Yaml and converting it to json. I've a challenge here, Im creating a R53 private zone so need to set a A record for the server in autoscalinggroup1 which will have only one server without scaling policies. Is there any way we could pull the Private ip address from autoscaling group? I know we can do it with awscli but I want to do this automatically with cloudformation. We can do having a elb attach to the server and get endpoints but I'm not looking for that way.

Thanks,
Swaroop.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: no.

Long answer is a little that you can use various commands and tricks to get the IP **after** the instance has spun up, then talk to the DNS service of your choice to setup the new IP with a hostname.

I've done this with dyndns and AWS::Route53.  It's really just a matter of orchestrating your workflow and getting the bits in place.

Another option is to use a static IP, but, again, same issue, it's a matter of getting your workflow and process down so that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, we have a solutions by the "`EC2 Auto Scaling lifecycle hooks`", just refer the links below,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/automating-ec2-auto-scaling-with-eventbridge.html